# UIWebview grey box at bottom after animation

Tags: animation, uiwebview

I've been trying to animate a uiwebview by making its frame shorter height using the `UIView` `animateWithDuration:animations:` method. I successfully shorten the uiwebview by making the frame property equal to a shorter height however when i scroll to the bottom of the uiwebview I find a grey box.

After I animate the uiwebview to be shorter height I animate the uiwebview to be longer height (back to normal height it was originally), and the grey box disappears (and it's animated, too).

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea how I can get rid of the grey box at the bottom of the uiwebview when i animate it to be shorter (via the frame property).

- I've tried reloading the webview (via the `reload` method).
- I've tried `setNeedsDisplay`.
- I've tried setting the `contentMode` to redraw.
- `Scale Pages to Fit` is off (I'd rather that it be off because otherwise my content shrinks too much).